# Wordpress Blog on Subdirectory but posts to appear as on home page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, joomla, blogs, subdirectory

I have redesigned a Wordpress website with Joomla. I still would like to keep the blog on Wordpress though, so I could install it under `domain.com/blog` and import all the content. However, all posts would now be under `/blog` and I need to prevent that if possible because I'm afraid the website may lose SEO if all these links are changed. Basically, I want to have the Wordpress on a subdirectory, but still need to have posts appear under `domain.com/post-name`, rather than `domain.com/blog/post-name`. Is there any way at all to do this?

Comment: You can do this in your htaccess file although rather than adding simple redirect to point to domain.com/post-name you are better off using 301 directs to point the old page to the new one.

Comment: Joe, thing is I'm not talking about 301 redirects. I want the actual old URL to stay the same without having a subdirectory URL intervene in the middle.

Comment: let say the WordPress pages retain their existing URLs. How do you want to differentiate the URLs of Joomla pages and WordPress pages?

Comment: I'm not really worried about differentiating them at this point. Wordpress pages will only be accessible from the landing page of Wordpress. I'm more worried about hurting SEO by changing indexed URLs than that. The way original wordpress website was set up, it didn't differentiate between blog post pages and other actual "pages".

Comment: @GeorgeC, like I said, you need to use 301 redirects for ALL links currently indexed in Google to you new pages at domain.com/blog/post-name. You will loose NO SEO juice from doing this. This is the correct way to do it, as per Google. I have done it with many sites as well. In no time, all pages will be in the SERP's under domain.com/blog/post-name and further, all new posts will be correctly indexed. Again, this is the proper way to do this.

Comment: Once all existing links are updated in the SERP's, which won't take long, you can remove the 301's and you're all good.